# Create Multiple arrays from a CSV file

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell

Currently I have a working solution:

```
#Declare Variables
$PMArray = @()
$SMArray = @()

#Get Input File and put information in 2 Arrays, 1 for Personal Mailboxes
#and 1 for Shared Mailboxes

Import-Csv "C:\inputfile.csv" -Delimiter ';' | foreach {
    $InputMBXType =  $_."MailboxType"
    $InputL =  $_."Level"
    $InputSMTP =  $_."PrimarySMTPAddress"

    if ($InputMBXType -eq "Personal Mailbox") {
        $PMObject = New-Object psobject
        $PMObject | Add-Member NoteProperty 'MailboxType' $InputMBXType
        $PMObject | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Level' $InputL
        $PMObject | Add-Member NoteProperty 'EmailAddress' $InputSMTP

        $PMArray += $PMObject
    }

    if ($InputMBXType -eq "Shared Mailbox") {
        $SMObject = New-Object psobject
        $SMObject | Add-Member NoteProperty 'MailboxType' $InputMBXType
        $SMObject | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Level' $InputL
        $SMObject | Add-Member NoteProperty 'EmailAddress' $InputSMTP

        $SMArray += $SMObject
    }
}

#Split Arrays by department

#Personal Mailboxes
$ABCpmarray = $PMArray | Where-Object {$_.Level -eq "ABC"}
$DEFpmarray = $PMArray | Where-Object {$_.Level -eq "DEF"}
$GHIpmarray = $PMArray | Where-Object {$_.Level -eq "GHI"}

#Shared Mailboxes
$ABCsmarray = $SMArray | Where-Object {$_.Level -eq "ABC"}
$DEFsmarray = $SMArray | Where-Object {$_.Level -eq "DEF"}
$GHIsmarray = $SMArray | Where-Object {$_.Level -eq "GHI"}

#Split Array in batches of defined number per batch
[int]$splitat = 50

#ABCpmarray
$runcount = [math]::Ceiling($ABCpmarray.count/$splitat)
for ($LN=0; $LN -lt $runcount; $LN++) {
    [int]$begin = $($LN * $splitat)
    [int]$end = $(($LN +1) * $splitat) -1
    $count = "{0:D2}" -f $LN
    $sel = $ABCpmarray[$begin..$end]
    $sel | select EmailAddress | Export-Csv -Path "C:\ABC-Personal-$count.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}

#ABCsmarray
$runcount = [math]::Ceiling($ABCsmarray.count/$splitat)
for ($LN=0; $LN -lt $runcount; $LN++) {
    [int]$begin = $($LN * $splitat)
    [int]$end = $(($LN +1) * $splitat) -1
    $count = "{0:D2}" -f $LN
    $sel = $ABCsmarray[$begin..$end]
    $sel | select EmailAddress | Export-Csv -Path "C:\ABC-Shared-$count.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}

#DEFpmarray
$runcount = [math]::Ceiling($DEFpmarray.count/$splitat)
for ($LN=0; $LN -lt $runcount; $LN++) {
    [int]$begin = $($LN * $splitat)
    [int]$end = $(($LN +1) * $splitat) -1
    $count = "{0:D2}" -f $LN
    $sel = $DEFpmarray[$begin..$end]
    $sel | select EmailAddress | Export-Csv -Path "C:\DEF-Personal-$count.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}

#DEFsmarray
$runcount = [math]::Ceiling($DEFsmarray.count/$splitat)
for ($LN=0; $LN -lt $runcount; $LN++) {
    [int]$begin = $($LN * $splitat)
    [int]$end = $(($LN +1) * $splitat) -1
    $count = "{0:D2}" -f $LN
    $sel = $DEFsmarray[$begin..$end]
    $sel | select EmailAddress | Export-Csv -Path "C:\DEF-Shared-$count.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Unfortunately all the departments are hard-coded in the script.

I would like to use a CSV file with all the departments.
Based on the CSV, new arrays must be created and filled with content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse string from column in csv in Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957666/how-to-parse-string-from-column-in-csv-in-powershell)

Comment: @mkierc I have read the post that you have suggested, but my question is different from the post that you sugest.

Comment: @ThomasMuller While that might be true it is worth it to explain _why_. Not just simply stating it is different.

Comment: There is a lot of code here that is repeated. For the purpose of an MCVE can you reduce this to a simple set and show how you manually created them? Is `$_.Level -eq "ABC"` what you meant by hardcoded department? What is `$PMArray` and `$SMArray`

Comment: Dear @Matt I use import csv function to load a csv file with users  AD/Exchange information. I have a column in my csv with the name Level. Level = Department. So for example when i have 10 rows with 10 different  users/departments. i need to export those records into different csv files. So i though i will create different arrays for each department and then export to csv. PMArray = Personal Mailbox Array and SMArray = Shared maibox Array.

Comment: Is there a reason that `$PMArray` and `$SMArray` are filtered the exact same in your example?

Comment: @Matt I have updated the script with my import function. Perhaps that makes it more understandable. Is it a little bit more clear what my issue is?

Comment: A good first step would probably be to refactor the array filtering and the `for` loops into a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need separate arrays. From the looks of it you are just using these arrays to help parse the output into different files. The information is all there and you can parse directly, so to speak, from the `Import-CSV`. As [shown by JohnLBeven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34520489/3829407) we can use Group-Object to replace most of the logic you used in creating the arrays.

I mocked some data for testing using www.mockaroo.com

```
MailboxType      PrimarySMTPAddress         Level
-----------      ------------------         -----
Personal Mailbox dgonzalesb@imageshack.us   ABC  
Shared Mailbox   klong9@cbc.ca              ABC  
Shared Mailbox   kchapman1@arstechnica.com  ABC  
Personal Mailbox pbowmanf@deliciousdays.com DEF  
Personal Mailbox charris5@addthis.com       DEF  
Personal Mailbox jhughesi@addtoany.com      DEF  
Shared Mailbox   chuntg@sun.com             DEF  
Shared Mailbox   apalmerd@163.com           DEF  
Shared Mailbox   dperez8@chron.com          DEF  
Shared Mailbox   jwilsona@nature.com        DEF  
Shared Mailbox   khayesc@nhs.uk             DEF  
Personal Mailbox jnelsonh@newsvine.com      GHI  
Personal Mailbox epetersone@microsoft.com   GHI  
Personal Mailbox sfuller0@forbes.com        GHI  
Personal Mailbox swoods6@taobao.com         GHI  
Personal Mailbox kbradley4@ft.com           GHI  
Personal Mailbox chill3@umn.edu             GHI  
Personal Mailbox jgarza2@guardian.co.uk     GHI  
Personal Mailbox sturner7@moonfruit.com     GHI  
Shared Mailbox   swagnerj@amazon.de         GHI
```

---

```
$rawdata = Import-CSV 'C:\MOCK_DATA.csv' -Delimiter ';'
$exportFolder = "C:\temp\test"
# Max number of entries per output file.
[int]$carve = 3

# Group 
$rawdata | Group-Object MailboxType | ForEach-Object{
    # Data is now grouped by MailboxType.
    $currentType = $_.Name -replace "\s+Mailbox$"s

    # Group this data by Level now
    $_.Group |  Group-Object Level | ForEach-Object{

        # Carve up the elements into chucks. Each group then written to its own file.
        for([int]$index = 0;$index -lt $_.Group.Count;$index+=$carve){ 

            # Collect the current chuck and send it to its own file. 
            $_.Group[$index..($index + $carve - 1)] | 
                Select @{Name="EmailAddress";Expression={$_.PrimarySMTPAddress}} |
                Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path ("$exportfolder\{0}-{1}-{2:D2}.csv" -f $_.Name, $currentType, ($index / $Carve + 1))
        }
    }
}
```

First group by the mailbox type. Then group by level. Carve up those arrays based on the `$carve` integer. Export the custom file name based on all of those attributes.

Using my above test data the following csv files were created

```
ABC-Personal-01.csv                                                                                                                        
ABC-Shared-01.csv                                                                                                                          
DEF-Personal-01.csv                                                                                                                        
DEF-Shared-01.csv                                                                                                                          
DEF-Shared-02.csv                                                                                                                          
GHI-Personal-01.csv                                                                                                                        
GHI-Personal-02.csv                                                                                                                        
GHI-Personal-03.csv                                                                                                                        
GHI-Shared-01.csv
```

Comment: Thank you Matt. Your script did the work. It looks much cleaner this way!

Answer (score 0):

1. The `Group-Object` functionality does pretty much what you want; all data will be put into one object, but you can then use the group name to pull back the related group's array:

   ```
   $AllArrays = $PMArray | Group-Object -Property Level

   $AllArrays | %{
       "Group Name: $($_.Name)" 
       $_ | select -ExpandProperty Group | ft -HideTableHeaders 
   }
   ```
2. You can save yourself some effort on the `foreach` loop by simply pulling the values from the CSV and filtering as below:

   ```
   [psobject[]]$PMArray = Import-Csv "C:\inputfile.csv" -Delimiter ';' `
   | ?{$_.MailboxType -eq "Personal Mailbox"} `
   | select MailboxType, Level, @{Name = 'EmailAddress'; Expression = {$_.PrimarySMTPAddress}}

   [psobject[]]$SMArray = Import-Csv "C:\inputfile.csv" -Delimiter ';' `
   | ?{$_.MailboxType -eq "Shared Mailbox"} `
   | select MailboxType, Level, @{Name = 'EmailAddress'; Expression = {$_.PrimarySMTPAddress}}
   ```